# Error to host live laravel website through xampp

Tags: php, laravel, windows, xampp, windows-server-2022

I want to host my live website in windows server through xampp but I tried few things and nothing is working at all.

My xampp apache server is working in port number :81 and :4433

When I point my domain name to my server ip address then by default it points to :80 thats why it is not working because :80 is being used by IIS.

In my domains A record also I can add like myip:81 because in A record they don't accept port number.

Can we do something to host my website in xampp? that is working in :81 port number?

There is no any solution in internet also looking for solution :(

Comment: Just don't use xampp

Comment: Nothing wrong with xampp, but if you enter a domain in the normal way to a browsers address, it will always default top port 80 for http and port 443 for https. If you want to use a NON STANDARD port you will have enter the port into the address bar like `https://example.com:4433`

Comment: @ericmp what is the other solution except xamp for windows server? because I have windows server

Comment: @RiggsFolly what is the other solution except xamp for windows server? because I have windows server

Comment: @ArjunGhimire idk, I'd use Linux to deploy